# How do I trigger an animation in A-frame 1.0.4?

Tags: javascript, animation, triggers, aframe, emit

After reading through the a-frame animation documentation, I was working around with some code in JSFiddle to get an idea of how it actually works. Seemed pretty simple... Until I tried to apply it to my own project. What was working in JSFiddle, doesn't work in my project. The console returns the error: "document.querySelector(...).emit is not a function". In the fiddle I was working on, a-frame was set to its 0.3.0 version. I need to use the most recent version - 1.0.4. Is there an alternative to "emit"?

Here's the JSFiddle, and a code snippet. Both are working with the 0.3.0 version of A-Frame.If you change the script src from "https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js" to "https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js" though, you will observe that it no longer works.
https://jsfiddle.net/6y5qbr4z/

```js
function lookAway() {
    document.getElementById("myCam").innerHTML = '<a-animation id="away" begin="move-away" attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="20 20 0"></a-animation>';
    setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('#away').emit('move-away');}, 1)  
    }
```

```css
.sceneWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn01" type="button" name="button" onclick="lookAway();">Look Away</button>

<div class="sceneWrapper">
    <a-scene embedded>
        <a-camera id="myCam" wasd-controls-enabled="false" look-controls="reverseMouseDrag:true">
        </a-camera>
        <a-sky src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg/1920px-Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg"></a-sky>
        <a-sphere id="ball" material="color: red" position="0 1.5 -5"></a-sphere>
    </a-scene>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your examples both the JS fiddle and the code snipet provided. on my local machine i.e through create a html page, add script, css and test,both are working without any errors.

[image]

I got this error when I block the aframe.io libraty from loading in the network tab.Can you please confirm that this is not the case.

- Are you triggering the lookAway() function before aframe.io library has loaded ?
- Is your library loading properly ?

If the above reasons are not one of the reasons for your error.please can you provide more info.

I also checked the checked the documentation for an alernative of .emit function

emit : emits a custom DOM event on the entity. For example, we can emit an event to trigger an animation

So we can trigger custom DOM evennts using javascript as well. please refer snippet for example.

```js
function moveAway() {
            document.getElementById("myCam").innerHTML = '<a-animation id="away" begin="move-away" attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="20 20 0"></a-animation>';
            // setTimeout(function(){
            //     document.querySelector('#away').emit('move-away');}, 
            // 1)  
            setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('#away').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("move-away", {
                bubbles: true
            })));
        }
```

```css
.sceneWrapper {
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 20px;
            height: 100vh;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn01" type="button" name="button" onclick="moveAway();">Move Away</button>

    <div class="sceneWrapper">
    <a-scene embedded>
        <a-camera id="myCam" wasd-controls-enabled="false" look-controls="reverseMouseDrag:true">
        </a-camera>
        <a-sky src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg/1920px-Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg"></a-sky>
        <a-sphere id="ball" material="color: red" position="0 1.5 -5"></a-sphere>
    </a-scene>
    </div>
```

---

I get your point now, sorry I didnt notice the version above

The `<a-animation>` element was deprecated in a-frame 0.9.0 in favor of the animation component.

It should look a little bit like this:

```
<a-camera id="myCam" wasd-controls-enabled="false" rotation="0 0 0" look-controls="reverseMouseDrag:true" animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: false; dur: 10000; startEvents: move-away">
```

please refer example implementation example

```js
function moveAway() {
            // document.getElementById("myCam").setAttribute("animation", "property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: false; dur: 10000; startEvents: move-away")
            // document.getElementById("myCam").innerHTML = '<a-animation id="away" begin="move-away" attribute="rotation" dur="2000" to="20 20 0"></a-animation>';
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.querySelector('#myCam').emit('move-away');}, 
            1)  
        }
```

```css
.sceneWrapper {
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 20px;
            height: 100vh;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn01" type="button" name="button" onclick="moveAway();">Move Away</button>

    <div class="sceneWrapper">
    <a-scene embedded>
        <a-camera id="myCam" wasd-controls-enabled="false" rotation="0 0 0" look-controls="reverseMouseDrag:true" animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: false; dur: 10000; startEvents: move-away">
        </a-camera>
        <a-sky src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg/1920px-Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg"></a-sky>
        <a-sphere id="ball" material="color: red" position="0 1.5 -5"></a-sphere>
    </a-scene>
    </div>
```

Please do let me know if anything else is needed.

Thank you

Comment: The examples are working on version 0.3.0. I need it to work on version 1.0.4. If you replace the src of the script tag from "https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js" to "https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js" you confirm the problem. I am getting the same error as shown in your printscreen. My library is loading properly. I have the script tag linking to the a-frame library in the head of the html. The function that rotates the camera is being called at the end of the html body. The alternative function you presented also doesn't work on version 1.0.4. Any other ideas?

Comment: I will edit the question to make it more clear that the example is working, but not on the version I need it to.

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer abit based on the version of the library mentioned. 1.0.4. Please do let me know i it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is a huge help. However I am still having a problem. After the animation plays, the camera rotation (in your example, the position) returns to its default values. You can test it by moving the camera around in your snippet, above, and only then click on the button. It will move 360º and then jump to its original position.